# combine data from 2 data frames in one plot using different graphs

Tags: r

I would like to combine a line plot and a scatter plot in one graph. The data comes from different data frames and the columns have different names. This is my reproducible example, which throws an error:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- runif(1000, min = 0, max = 100)
y <- rnorm(1000, mean = 50, sd = 30)
df1 <- data.frame(
      x = x
      , y = y
)

x1 <- runif(10, min = 0, max = 100)
y1 <- rnorm(10, mean = 50, sd = 30)
df2 <- data.frame(
      x1 = x1
      , y1= y1
)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(df2, aes(x1, y1))
```

Comment: Use `geom_point(aes(x1, y1), df2)`. Layers (eg., `geom_point`) have different argument ordering than main `ggplot` call (ie, in layers `aes` goes first).

Comment: close vote?! common!

Comment: Isn't this a typo or *why is this code not working*? imo, you're passing wrong arguments.

Comment: 2 up votes and one close vote. whoever voted for close have some guts and elicit your reasons!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overplotting from different data frames in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516017/overplotting-from-different-data-frames-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to upload data on each `geom_*` separately:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df1, aes(x, y), color = "grey") +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x1, y1), color = "red")
```

[image]