# How to plot plots using different datasets using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to plot a line and a dot using ggplot2. I looked [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329851/how-can-i-add-another-layer-new-series-to-a-ggplot) but it assumes the same dataset is used. What I tried to do is

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(Credible=c(0.2, 0.3),
                 len=c(0, 0))

zero=data.frame(x0=0,y0=0)

 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Credible, y=len, group=1)) +
  geom_line(color="red")+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x = "Credible", y = "")

  ggplot(data=zero, aes(x=x0, y=y0, group=1)) +
  geom_point(color="green")+
  labs(x = "Credible", y = "")
```

but it generates just the second plot (the dot).

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476022/geom-point-and-geom-line-for-multiple-datasets-on-same-graph-in-ggplot2?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the careful and reproducible way you created your question I am not just referring to the old answer as it may be harder to transfer the subsetting etc.

You initialize a new `ggplot` object whenever you run `ggplot(...)`.

If you want to add a layer on top of an existing plot you have to operate on the same object, something like this:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Credible, y=len, group=1)) +
  geom_line(color="red")+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x = "Credible", y = "") +
  geom_point(data=zero, color="green", aes(x=x0, y=y0, group=1))
```

Note how in the second `geom_point` the data source and aesthetics are explicitly specified instead to prevent them being inherited from the initial object.

Comment: The second `labs(x = "Credible", y = "")` is redundant and you can remove it :)

Comment: yeah copy and pasting not so smart  :)